# Change default browser while using scrapy's shell view function

Tags: scrapy, python-webbrowser, scrapy-shell

While on a scrapy shell, when I try to use the `view(response)` function, instead of opening a browser, it opens Visual Studio Code. How to make it open on a browser?

I read that `webbrowser` is the library used to view the page and that I could set the `BROWSER` variable to change its default. On a Linux Mint system, to which value should I change the `BROWSER` variable to in order to make the `view` command to open firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself after some further searching.

The value of the `BROWSER` variable should be `/usr/bin/firefox`.

So, in my case, adding the following line to my `~/.bashrc` file did the trick:
`export BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox`.